# How can i create this type of html layout

Tags: html, layout, alignment

I want to create something like this in a layout where the icon line themselves up with html, how can i get this done?

[Layout i would like to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OJX.png)

I Tried the following without flexbox, but when the width gets to narrow it messes up. guess i should try the flexbox instead., hope that will work.

[good version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLB4y.png)
[messed up version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giBTA.png)

```css
    .pageColumnMid{
margin-right:20px;
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : auto;
    }
    .pageColumnLeft{
text-align:left;
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : auto;
    }
    .pageColumnRight{
        margin-left:20px;
    float : left;
    clear : none;
    height : auto;
    width : auto;
    }
    .lineheight50{
        line-height: 40px!important;
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div><div>
    <div class="pageColumnMid"><span  class="fas fa-user lineheight50" ></span> <br> <span  class="fas fa-user lineheight50" ></span> <br> <span  class="fas fa-user lineheight50" ></span> <br>
    </div>
    <div class="pageColumnLeft lineheight50" >View, manage and publish your personal data <br> View, manage and store your Contacts <br> View your technicaldata* <br>
    </div>
    <div class="pageColumnRight"></span><span  class="fas fa-info lineheight50" ></span> <br>  <span  class="fas fa-info lineheight50" ></span> <br>  <span  class="fas fa-info lineheight50" ></span> <br>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Seems like its not mobile responsive, please check my new question about the mobile responsiveness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your design this is what you can do as shown below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;/*can edit as per requirement*/
}

.d-flex .col .child {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.d-flex .col {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.d-flex p {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!--ADD THIS LINE TO GET FONTAWESOME ICONS IN HEAD TAG-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child">
      <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
      <p>View, manage and publish your personal data</p>
    </div>
    <span class="fas fa-info"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child">
      <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
      <p>View, manage and store your Contacts</p>
    </div>
    <span class="fas fa-info"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="child">
      <span class="fas fa-user"></span>
      <p>View your technicaldata*</p>
    </div>
    <span class="fas fa-info"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should learn about Flex in CSS
By using these attributes you'll get what you want...

```
display: flex;  //Flexible Box Layout
flex-wrap: wrap; // box automatically go to next line
flex-direction: column;   // boxes are arranged int column order.
```

To play with these attributes and other also make you more clear about flex.
Thanks